# Pointer not passing object correctly

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to make the stack in c++ but seem to be running into a problem.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {

public:

    int node_value;
    Node * previous_node;

};



class Stack {

public:
    Node * node_pointer;
    int size = 0;

    void push(int number) {

        Node NewNode;

        NewNode.node_value = number;
        cout << number << endl;


        if (size == 0) {

            node_pointer = &NewNode;
            cout << node_pointer << endl;
            size += 1;
            cout << "Pushed" << endl;

        }

        else if (size > 0)
        {
            NewNode.previous_node = node_pointer;
            node_pointer = &NewNode;
            cout << "Pushed" << endl;
            size += 1;
        }
    }

    void pop() {

        if (size > 1) {

            Node Temp_Node = *node_pointer;
            cout << Temp_Node.node_value << endl;
            node_pointer = Temp_Node.previous_node;
            size -= 1;
        }

        else if (size == 1){
            size -= 1;
            Node Temp = *node_pointer;
            cout << Temp.node_value;

        }

        else {
            cout << "empty" << endl;
        }

    }



};


int main()
{
    Stack stack;
    Node a;
    Node b;
    Node * p1;
    int num = 5;
    a.node_value = num;
    p1 = &a;
    b = *p1;
    cout << b.node_value << endl;
    stack.push(10);
    stack.pop();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of returning the node value it returns an address. I'm kind of confused because when I did the same thing with just nodes it worked just fine. In the stack I copy the address into the pointer node_pointer and when i make a new node by derefencing the pointer it spits back completely different instance variables.

Comment: This address? `cout << node_pointer << endl;`

Comment: The only function in this program that returns a value is `main`. You need to expand on where the error is and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from function push(), the 'newNode' is a variable on the stack, and the compiler will automatically invoke its destructor at the end of the function.
To avoid this, you should use 'new' operator to create the 'newNode' on the heap, and function pop() has the responsibility to deallocate the memory(use 'delete' operator).
If the 'new' and 'delete' operator confuse you, you can use 'std::shared_ptr' instead.

```
void push(int number) {

    Node *NewNode = new Node{};

    NewNode->node_value = number;

    if (size == 0) {

        node_pointer = NewNode;
        cout << node_pointer << endl;
        size++;
        cout << "Pushed" << endl;

    }

    else if (size > 0)
    {
        NewNode->previous_node = node_pointer;
        node_pointer = NewNode;
        size++;
        cout << "Pushed" << endl;
    }
}

void pop() {

    if (size > 1) {

        Node* Temp_Node = node_pointer;
        cout << Temp_Node->node_value << endl;
        delete node_pointer;
        node_pointer = Temp_Node->previous_node;
        size--;
    }

    else if (size == 1) {
        Node* Temp = node_pointer;
        cout << Temp->node_value << endl;
        delete node_pointer;
        node_pointer = nullptr;
        size--;
    }

    else {
        cout << "empty" << endl;
    }

}
```

Also you can take the advantage of SmartPointer: you have no responsibility to 'new' and 'delete' object on the heap.

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class Node {
    using node_ptr = std::shared_ptr<Node>;
public:
    int node_value;
    node_ptr previous_node;
};

class Stack {
    using node_ptr = std::shared_ptr<Node>;
public:
    node_ptr node_pointer = nullptr;
    int size = 0;

void push(int number) {

    node_ptr NewNode = std::make_shared<Node>();

    NewNode->node_value = number;

    if (size == 0) {
        node_pointer = NewNode;
        cout << node_pointer << endl;
        size++;
        cout << "Pushed" << endl;
    }

    else if (size > 0)
    {
        NewNode->previous_node = node_pointer;
        node_pointer = NewNode;
        size++;
        cout << "Pushed" << endl;
    }
}

void pop() {

    if (size > 1) {

        node_ptr Temp_Node = node_pointer;
        cout << Temp_Node->node_value << endl;
        //delete node_pointer; 
        //no need to delete here, it will be automatically destructed when Temp_Node leaves this scope.
        node_pointer = Temp_Node->previous_node;
        size--;
    }

    else if (size == 1) {
        node_ptr Temp = node_pointer;
        cout << Temp->node_value << endl;
        //delete node_pointer;
        node_pointer = nullptr;
        size--;
    }

    else {
        cout << "empty" << endl;
    }

}
```

};

Comment: A random comment on this - generally prefer unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr unless you really need shared ownership. In this case, the stack class should be the unique owner of the objects.

Comment: @Charlie Thanks for comment. Right, Stack Container has no need to expose the inner structure detail outside.

Answer (score 4):

One *major* problem are these two lines:

```
Node NewNode;
...
node_pointer = &NewNode;
```

The first line defines a ***local*** variable. Then you save a pointer to that local variable. And that variable will go out of scope and the object `NewNode` will be destructed when the function ends. Leaving you with an invalid pointer.

Dereferencing that invalid pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The standard solution is to allocate the nodes dynamically with `new`:

```
Node* NewNode = new Node;
...
node_pointer = NewNode;
```

Of course, you have to remember to `delete` the nodes once you're done with them.

Comment: Thank you very much! I made the NewNode part of the stack and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Making NewNode part of the stack isn't the correct solution. You can allocate your NewNode on the heap to extend its lifetime. Just make sure you delete all that memory in your destructor (something you should be doing anyway if you're not using smart pointers).

Comment: @SaltedNuke What do you mean by "part of the stack"? What "stack"? How did you make it a "part" of that "stack"?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude he probably means the Stack class (as in making NewNode a member variable of the class).

Comment: @A.Laribi If that is so, then it's wrong as well (as you written).

Comment: @A.Laribi Thanks for the comment and answer, You were right. It was only a temporary solution. I wasn't aware of the new neither delete operator.